# Export as csv in beeline hive

Tags: csv, hive, beeline

I am trying to export my hive table as a csv in beeline hive. When I run the command `!sql select * from database1 > /user/bob/output.csv` it gives me syntax error.

I have successfully connected to the database at this point using the below command. The query outputs the correct results on console.

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv
```

Also, not very clear where the file ends up. It should be the file path in hdfs correct?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When hive version is at least 0.11.0 you can execute:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/directoryWhereToStoreData' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
SELECT * FROM yourTable;
```

from hive/beeline to store the table **into a directory** on the local filesystem.

---

Alternatively, with beeline, save your SELECT query in yourSQLFile.sql and run:

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv2 -f yourSQlFile.sql > theFileWhereToStoreTheData.csv
```

Also this will store the result **into a file** in the local file system.

---

From hive, to store the data somewhere into HDFS:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE output 
LIKE yourTable 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION 'hfds://WhereDoYou/Like';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE output SELECT * from yourTable;
```

then you can collect the data to a local file using:

```
hdfs dfs -getmerge /WhereDoYou/Like
```

This is another option to get the data using beeline only:

```
env HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Ddisable.quoting.for.sv=false" beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://your.hive.server.address:10000/" --incremental=true --outputformat=csv2 -e "select * from youdatabase.yourtable"
```

---

Working on:

```
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.1.0-cdh5.10.1)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.1.0-cdh5.10.1)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.10.1 by Apache Hive
```

Comment: One weird thing I noticed, `--outputformat` doesn't work if you place it after the `-e` query or `-f` file with query switches. Strange I thought these were named arguments but seems beeline ignores any args after the query. I kept getting the default table format.

Comment: Please add the versions since Hadoop ecosystem is a work in progress.

Comment: I'm using this on AWS, if I run `beeline --version` it shows me Hive 2.3.2-amzn-0

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Your CLI statement really helped me move my project forward!

Comment: this certainly make the fields delimited by comma but it doesn't guarantee it is a CSV, right? is it possible to specify the escape character, quote character or all those goodies have already been taking care of and this will guarantee a legit CSV.

Comment: Don't know it. I can read it using the Python library CSV and other minor tools I use. Since I never faced any issues in importing this file, I never feel the need to find a way to set so many details in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command to save output in CSV format from `beeline`:

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://bigdataplatform-dev.nam.nsroot.net:10000/;principal=hive/bigdataplatform-dev.net@NAMUXDEV.NET;ssl=true' --outputformat=csv2 --verbose=false  --fastConnect=true   --silent=true -f $query_file>out.csv
```

Save your SQL query file into $query_file.

Result will be in out.csv.

I have complete example here: [hivehoney](https://github.com/hive-scripts/hivehoney/blob/master/pbrun.exp)

Answer (score 3):

Following worked for me

```
hive --silent=true --verbose=false --outputformat=csv2 -e "use <db_name>; select * from <table_name>" > table_name.csv
```

One advantage over using beeline is that you don't have have to provide hostname or user/pwd if you are running on hive node.

When some of the columns have string values having commas, tsv (tab separated) works better

```
hive --silent=true --verbose=false --outputformat=tsv -e "use <db_name>; select * from <table_name>" > table_name.tsv
```

Answer (score 3):

Output format in CSV:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.41:10000/test_db -n user1 -p password **--outputformat=csv2** -e "select * from t1";
```

Output format in custom delimiter:

```
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.41:10000/test_db -n user1 -p password **--outputformat=dsv** **--delimiterForDSV='|'** -e "select * from t1";
```

Running command in background and redirect out to file:

```
$nohup `$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.41:10000/test_db -n user1 -p password --outputformat=csv2 -e "select * from t1"; > output.csv 2> log` &
```

Reference URLs:

https://dwgeek.com/export-hive-table-into-csv-format-using-beeline-client-example.html/
https://dwgeek.com/hiveserver2-beeline-command-line-shell-options-examples.html/

Answer (score 0):

**From Beeline**

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://123.12.4132:345/database_name' --outputformat=csv2 -e "select col1, col2, col3 from table_name" > /path/to/dump.csv