# Writing Impala query results in a file

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I need to store the result of an Impala query in a text file with no other information but the data itself.
For example: `select distinct yrmth from test.abc` 
It should write:
201705
201706 etc.
in a text file line by line.

Any leads?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export as csv in beeline hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577036/export-as-csv-in-beeline-hive)

Comment: Please provide me the Impala-shell syntax for the same.

Comment: Beeline connects to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

impala-shell is well documented. You should try reading the help manual first. Anyway, here is your answer.

```
impala-shell -q 'select distinct yrmth from test.abc' -B -o res.txt
```