# Save Hive query results as xlsx on Hue

Tags: excel, hadoop, hive, hue

Cloudera Hue has the option to export results of a Hive query directly as an Excel xlsx file. That is however a manual option, the user has to manually click on the button to export the file.

Is there an underlying function that can be called e.g. by the HiveSQL query itself to automate the export into the Excel format?

Comment: As for as I am aware, No such function is available.

Comment: You can't automate this in Hue, and CSV is a more universal format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577036/export-as-csv-in-beeline-hive