# Export/Import databases using beeline

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I have some database in My Hiveserver2 which I need to export to hdfs and than import them to an other cluster (other hiveserver).

I see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577036/export-as-csv-in-beeline-hive) but it's csv form.
I would like also know if there's a such command "export $database" and "import $database"

Comment: look at the discussion here.. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5582/export-hive-database.html

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala is that works for Beeline or Mysql?