# Splitting hive query output as comma separate value

Tags: shell, hive

I am trying to load hive query output into a csv file, when i run below script

```
hive -e "select * from mytable" > output.csv
```

i want the output of row fields should be separated by commas.

Comment: `hive -e "select * from mytable" |awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' >output.csv` this is not complete answer

Comment: Look also at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755790/2700344

Answer (score 1):

You can write a sql query for that, which would be less error prone.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/mytable/data' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

if you have a beeline, it has an option to export the data into csv.

```
beeline --outputformat=csv2 -e "select * from mytable" > mytable.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it is working, but the results are getting into .gz files, Is there a way we can get the results into normal files

Comment: I need to load the hive query output into Teradata, .gz files creating issues with delimiter while loading to Teradata, but when i copy data into a flat file, i could load without issues.

Comment: which option are you talking about?