# How to speed up this query to retrieve lastUpdateTime of all hive tables?

Tags: bash, hive

I have created a bash script ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/surajiyer/Get-All-Hive-Tables-LastUpdateTime)) to query for all hive databases; query each table within them and parse the lastUpdateTime of those tables and extract them to a csv with columns "tablename,lastUpdateTime".

This query is however slow because in each iteration, the call to "hive -e..." starts a new hive cli command which takes noticeably significant amount of time to load.

Is there a way to speed up either loading up the hive cli or speed up the query in some other way to solve the same problem?

I have thought about loading the hive cli just once at the start of the script and try to call the bash commands from within the hive cli using the `! <command>` method but not sure how to do loops then within the cli and also if I can process the loops inside a bash script file and execute that, then I am not sure how to pass the results of queries executed within hive cli as arguments to this script.

Without giving specification about the system I am running it on, the script can process about ~10 tables per minute which I think is really slow considering there can be thousands of tables in the database we want to apply it on.

Comment: You can run Hive commands in parallel, like in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53755790/2700344 parametrize output filename to be like this  ${DB}.csv and add ampersand to the end. Add waiting like in my answer

Comment: I already do parallel processing of hive queries by using the -P argument in xargs http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html which I see is what you suggest towards the end of your answer also. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I see. Direct access to the metastore database then: https://sharebigdata.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/hive-metastore-internal-tables/